# How to replace an SC-Duplex-switch with an SFP switch?

Tags: optical-media, sfp

Currently I have some switches in our network, which use (besides the Fast Ethernet ports) also optical fiber with two SC-Duplex-Connectors (one in and one out). Now I want to replace these old devices by a newer model, but unfortunately modern switches mainly use the SFP interface for optical fiber, which is not directly compatible with our SC-Duplex connectors.

**What combination of devices and modules/adapters would be the most sustainable solution to this problem?** I mean, if a buy a modern SFP Switch, what would I need to do to connect my SC-Duplex-Connectors?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the most simple solution would be to purchase SC-to-LC patch cables.

Comment: As far as I know the SC-connector is bigger in size than the LC-connector. Is that not a problem?

Comment: Of course it is. :) That's the problem you're trying to solve. The fiber cores are the same diameter, though, regardless of what the connector looks like. Just make sure to get fiber that is compatible with the rest of your fiber plant.